# Adding local dependencies to contenerized application built by gradlew

Tags: java, docker, maven, gradle, gradlew

I' working on an application that I run locally via Docker. Most important part of the `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17 as source
COPY . /data
WORKDIR /data

FROM source as build
RUN ./gradlew clean build --info -x test
```

As you can see above jar is built by `gradle wrapper` that is present in the main application directory. Until now I worked only with central maven depndencies, so in my `build.gradle.kts` I had part like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

My current goal is to add some local dependencies. I added `mavenLocal()` to the above configuration and specify the dependency in `dependencies` part. It is possible for IntelliJ to add the jar to the `External Libraries`, but I have no idea how to build the application in the container. I tried to mount my local `.m2/repository` in `docker-compose.yml` as a volume like this:

```
volumes:
  - ./config:/config
  - ~/.m2/repository:/root/.m2/repository
```

And I can see that relevant jar is present in the container, but the ouput of the build process is still like this:

```
47.23 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
47.23 
47.23 * What went wrong:
47.23 Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
47.23 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
47.23    > Could not find com.x:y:0.0.0-main-SNAPSHOT.
47.23      Required by:
47.23          project :
```

What is the part that I'm missing? Do I need to add something more to `gradle` settings to inform `gradlew` that it should look for the files in some specific place? I tried to replace `mavenLocal()` with `maven(url = "/root/.m2/repository")` (or `maven(url = "~/.m2/repository"`) but it didn't work either. I run the build also with `--info` flag and the only logs relevant to this dependency were:

```
50.36 Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/x/y/0.0.0-main-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
50.36 Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/x/y/0.0.0-main-SNAPSHOT/y-0.0.0-main-SNAPSHOT.pom]
```

How can I deliver dependency from local maven repository to the build process?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was related not to gradle itself, but to Docker - volumes are mounted too late in the process, so gradle wasn't able to resolve the dependency, because `.m2` was not there yet. I copied repositories to the main application directory and modified `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17 as source
COPY . /data
COPY ./repository /root/.m2/repository
WORKDIR /data

FROM source as build
COPY --from=source /root/.m2/repository /root/.m2/repository
RUN ./gradlew clean build -x test
```

and everything is working as expected.